# Intersection Observer not running in FF

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

I have this piece of code that I use for Lazy loading images:

https://jsfiddle.net/uf9Ldptw/

```
//Link rel preload
const createPreloadLink = (href, listener) => {
    const link = document.createElement('link'); //meta tag link
    link.rel = 'preload';
    link.as = 'image';
    link.href = href;
    link.addEventListener('load', listener);
    document.head.appendChild(link);
};

const updateBackground = lazyloadEl => {
    if (lazyloadEl.classList.contains('loaded')) {
       return; // Do nothing if the photo is already loaded
    }
    const title = lazyloadEl.querySelector('.LazyLoadElement');
    title.style.backgroundImage = `url(${title.dataset.backgroundImage})`;
    lazyloadEl.classList.add('loaded');
};

const handler = entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.75) {
        updateBackground(entry.target);
      }
    });
};
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler, { threshold: 0.75 }); 
//Observer buildin browser. 25% on screen 

const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.lazyLoadContainer'); 

cards.forEach(lazyloadEl => {
    const title = lazyloadEl.querySelector('.LazyLoadElement');
    const observeEl = () => observer.observe(lazyloadEl);
    createPreloadLink(title.dataset.backgroundImage, observeEl);
});
```

Im using Intersection Obeserver since Im building an internal tool that only needs to be compatible with the latest version of Chrome and Firefox. I dont need any Safari or IE supports, so I didnt investigate polyfills.

This code does exactly what I want in Chrome, but in Firefox it doesnt work at all. Im not getting any errors, and from the documentation Intersection Obeserver is supported since Firefox 55, and Im currently on 63.

What am I missing there?

Comment: Have you checked the `about:config` of your Firefox browser to be sure the `dom.IntersectionObserver.enabled` preference is true? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Browser_compatibility I don't think that should be necessary but it might be.

Comment: Yes, I just checked and it is set to true

Comment: FWIW I think I can reproduce the apparent problem exhibited by your JSFiddle in my Firefox browser version 63. That is, it behaves differently from Chrome (shows only blue cards not white placeholder images).

Comment: Yes Firefox is my only problem, I would like it to behave like Chrome, where all blue squares are replaced with the white placeholder as the user scroll.